# Displaying musical symbols on Windows 8.1

Tags: unicode, symbols

So I came accross some unicode symboles that won't show anything besides a square with a hex number in it, after Googling it I was sent [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d107/browsertest.htm).

I can't use the symbol in text editors or in browsers and my region settings are set to English UK.

I'd like to be able to see the intended symbol and not just the square with its value in it.

The symbol I used is U+1D107 or .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that few fonts contain glyphs for characters like U+1D107 and apparently no such font is shipped with Windows 8. Thus, you need to download and install some suitable additional font(s).

The Fileformat.info page you mention has a link to a font support page, but it is not complete. The [Code2001](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/code2001.html) font has obscure status. FreeSerif, Quivira, and Symbola are possible choices. So is [Musica](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/).

Answer (score -1):

Check out the UniPad text editor. It should be able to display the symbol you're looking for.

http://www.unipad.org/download/

As for browsers, the following fonts include that symbol (see link below):

Code2001, FreeSerif, LastResort, Quivira, Symbola

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d107/fontsupport.htm

Comment: How about for my web browsers ? I mainly use Firefox but I also use Google Chrome.

Comment: Getting FreeFont from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/freefont/ did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: not a problem :)

Comment: This depends on fonts, not on programs (provided that a program can be made to use a suitable font, but that’s possible even in Notepad). LastResort is not a real font (look at it!).